# Javascript to display checked out documents to remind users

Tags: document-library, check-out

I am searching for a function to put in a content/Script editor that will just Display what and how many documents the user has to check in.

Google will not help me and i would prefer not to use the build in email reminder.

I want to put the webpart on the right side and just have it "Checked out to you. Doc1 Doc2 Doc3 etc".

## **Edit and Solution**

First of, thank you [Jenny](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/30392/jenny-hersko) and [Praveen](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/66379/praveen-pudi)

I ended up using a non scripted version. I created a view with only -type -Name ( with editing dots).

Since there is "Checked out too" in the system, just not in the view i can filter documents by only displaying if Checked out to and in the textbox **[Me]**
[image: Sharepoint filter view]

This was the easiest solution i could think off.

Answer (score 1):

Use below endpoint

```
/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('Documents')/files?$select=CheckedOutByUser/Title,Name&$expand=CheckedOutByUser&$filter=((CheckOutType ne 2 ) and(CheckedOutByUser/Title eq 'Praveen Pudi'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered non-JavaScript options?  There are two out of the box web parts that can display documents checked out to the logged in user.

1. Relevant Documents Web Part - Use this web part on a site-by-site basis.  The web part is typically in the Content Rollup category.
2. Content Search Web Part (SharePoint 2013 and later):  This web part can be configured to show checked out documents across a site collection, or, on a site-by-site basis.  Check out this blog for implementation steps:  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/396c42/retrieve-checked-out-documents-from-the-whole-site-collectio/